# Python: Match phrases in dictionary values to a sentence (the dictionary key) and output based on match

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, where each key is a sentence, and the values are particular words or phrases in that sentence.

for example:

```
dict1 = {'it is lovely weather and it is kind of warm':['lovely weather', 'it is kind of warm'],'and the weather is rainy and cold':['rainy and cold'],'the temperature is ok':['temperature']}
```

I would like my output to be each sentence tagged based on whether or not the phrase is in the dictionary values.

In this example, the output would be (where 0 is not in the values, and 1 is in the values)

```
*
it 0
is 0
lovely weather 1 (combined because it's a phrase)
and 0
it is kind of warm 1 (combined because it's a phrase)
*
and 0
the 0
weather 0
is 0
rainy and cold 1 (combined because it's a phrase)
...(and so on)...
```

I can get something like this to work, but only by hard coding the number of words in the phrase:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
   words_in_val = v.split()
   if len(words_in_val) == 1:
      words = k.split()
      for each_word in words:
             if v == each_word:
                   print(each_word + '\t' + '1')
             else:
                   print(each_word + '\t' + '0')


     if len(words_in_val) == 2::
         words = k.split()
         for index,item in enumerate(words[:-1]):
                if words[index] == words_in_val[0]:
                       if words[index+1] == words_in_val[1]:
                              words[index] = ' '.join(words_in_val)
                              words.remove(words[index+1])
                              ....something like this...
```

My issue is that i can see it starts to get messy, and also in theory, I can have an unlimited number of words in the phrase I want to match, although it's usually <10.

Would someone have a better idea of how to do this?

Comment: is this question being closed for being too vague?

Comment: thanks i didn't realise it would be so hard, i assumed i was just struggling to turn the above into a loop.

Comment: "a small group of words standing together as a conceptual unit, typically forming a component of a clause.". You'd have to have the program understand what a "conceptual unit" is, which I can see being difficult.

Comment: hmm I don't think so, does he not already have all the phrases and words in the value of the dictionary? so it's rather a look up. The problem is that he do all that if with different length which can be solved with a while (I only think about it in my head) but I don't see a need that the program understand phrases

Comment: Boendal this is more like what I was thinking, that it was more a case of just changing the loop to be something like 'split the phrase in the value...then for the length of the words in that phrase....divide the key/sentence up into overlapping chunks of the same length and check if they're equal' (i only know how to do in theory, not sure how to actually do it in real life).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't think it is right to close that question, I think you misunderstood what he wants. (see my comment above)

Comment: @Boendal That's possible. I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you

Comment: Can you clarify why you split key and value just to reassemble them? Based on your initial desired output, you just want to test ˋitem in keyˋ for each ˋitem in valueˋ. If this is not what you want, please clarify your matching rules. Also note that your example input and code does not match - for example, you call ˋv.split()ˋ which does not work on lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I would do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'it is lovely weather and it is kind of warm':['it is kind of', 'it is kind'],'and the weather is rainy and cold':['rainy and cold'],'the temperature is ok':['temperature']}

def tag_sentences(dict):
    id = 1
    tagged_results = []
    for sentence, phrases in dict.items():
        words = sentence.split()
        phrases_split = [phrase.split() for phrase in phrases]
        positions_keeper = {}
        sentence_results = [(word, 0) for word in words]
        for word_index, word in enumerate(words):
            for index, phrase in enumerate(phrases_split):
                position = positions_keeper.get(index, 0)
                if phrase[position] == word:
                    if len(phrase) > position + 1:
                        positions_keeper[index] = position + 1
                    else:
                        for i in range(len(phrase)):
                            sentence_results[word_index - i] = (sentence_results[word_index - i][0], id)
                        id = id + 1
                else:
                    positions_keeper[index] = 0
        tagged_results.append(sentence_results)
    return tagged_results

def print_tagged_results(tagged_results):
    for tagged_result in tagged_results:
        memory = 0
        memory_sentence = ""
        for result, id in tagged_result:
            if memory != 0 and memory != id:
                print(memory_sentence + "1")
                memory_sentence = ""
            if id == 0:
                print(result, 0)
            else:
                memory_sentence += result + " "
            memory = id
        if memory != 0:
            print(memory_sentence + "1")

tagged_results = tag_sentences(dict1)
print_tagged_results(tagged_results)
```

This is basically doing the following:

1. First I make a tagged list in the format: `[(it, 0), (is, 0), (lovely, 0) ...]`
2. In the tagged list I mark 0 => not in a group and other integer number as grouping together (words with tag 1 grouped together, words with tag 2 grouped together)
3. I iterate through each word and mark it if it match with the beginning of a phrase or if I'm already in the loop with the current phrase position
4. If it is the end of the phrase I mark the word and all words that matched in the past with this phrase with the same id
5. If it is not the end I will keep the position and start the next iteration.
6. In the end I have a tagged list in the format `[(it, 0), (is, 0), (lovely, 1) ... (kind,2), (of, 2), ...]`

It won't work if a phrase is a subphrase of another phrase but you never mention this in your example how it should react to this situation.